# Xcode error ld: framework not found AudioUnit clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I am new to Xcode. When I tried to build my app in Xcode it says build error and gives the following error

> ld: framework not found AudioUnit
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: ERROR SCREEN SHOT]

please help

Answer (score 0):

The `AudioUnit.framework` is for iOS 9.0 onwards and you are building for iOS 6.0.

You'll need to change your deployment target to iOS 9.0.

See the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUAudioUnit_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AUAudioUnit):

> Available in iOS 9.0 and later

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i did change the deployment target to iOS 9.0 but still get the same error please help